# Is it possible to automate this grid pattern in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photoshop-scripting

This is a grid pattern created in my country in the sixties, taking binary values for lights and shadows. I couldn't find this anywhere else, or maybe I'm not using the proper words for it. The literal translation would be something like *photohatch* but couldn't find anything like this. We did this in design school (this is before computers) as an analogic exercise

Anyways, take a look to the pictures and let me know if there's a way to do this in an automated way

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see anything that resembles a hatch pattern. Maybe there's a language problem here?  When you speak of a "hatch pattern" - [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/38/0a/02/380a02595cd07b6e4e9f05ea021a47da.jpg) is what comes to my mind. I think the word you might be looking for is a "grid", or even "pixelated".

Comment: thank you. Yes, tehre's a language barrier, the literal translation from Spanish is hatch, but you're correct, it's a grid. Either way still couldn't find it (but edited the post accordingly)

Comment: @user287001, black and white squares are black and white. Black dot over white square is a lighter gray, white dot on black square respresents darker grey shadows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say the pattern is binary, but in fact it consists of 4 different "tones":

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Create a pattern for each of the middle tones (with the circles) by making a selection and choosing *Edit > Define Pattern*. (In this example I've made the squares 32x32 px)

Convert the image you want to transform to grayscale and scale it down to a fitting size.

Let's take [this image of a monkey skull](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chlorocebus_perspective.jpg) by Didier Desouens (CC BY-SA 4.0), scale and crop it down to 36x36 px.

[image]

Then upscale the image by 3200% using Nearest Neigbor interpolation.

[image]

Now each pixel is the same size as the pattern squares: 32x32px.

Use *Image > Adjustments > Posterize* to reduce the image to consist of 4 levels.

[image]

[image]

Use *Magic Wand* with *Anti-alias* and *Contigous* ticked off and click one of the dark gray pixels. Add a *Pattern Fill* layer and select the dark square with a white circle.

Then click one of the light gray pixels and add a *Pattern Fill* layer with the white square with the black circle.

[image]

You can make another pattern to create a grid and get this final result:

[image]

Comment: wow, amazing, thank you Wolf!