# How to make custom halftone effect with more than one pattern?

Tags: patterns, image-editing, bitmap, halftone, ascii

I've only ever seen this done on one project, I can't remember the name or where I saw it but I did take a screenshot because I loved the idea.
I want to put a halftone/bitmap effect on an image, but not like usual where there is only 1 pattern at different sizes. Instead the there are several patterns that stay the same size. So I guess more like ASCII?

How would you go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/53543/18306

Comment: [This answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/137469/84899) is related and could work for your use. But there are other ways I guess. Like ASCII art generators for example.